# Oracle view with application context using "group by" returns no result without a strange hack

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have created a view in Oracle which intends to load parts of the data in a table, and limited by the parameters set in the application context:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SALT_RAW_SUMMARY AS
(
    select
        VENDOR_ID, PRD_CATEGORY, LOGIN_NAME, CURRENCY /*, Some more aggregated fields*/
    from
        VENDOR_RECORD
    where
        (
            order_time between SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptBeginTime') and SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptEndTime')
            AND order_time between SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_BEGIN_TIME') AND SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_END_TIME')
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID') = '*'
                or
                (
                    VENDOR_ID in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID') = '*'
                or
                (
                    VENDOR_ID in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    PRD_CATEGORY in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    PRD_CATEGORY in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME') = '*'
                or
                (
                    LOGIN_NAME in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    LOGIN_NAME in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    group by
        VENDOR_ID, PRD_CATEGORY, LOGIN_NAME, CURRENCY
);
```

However, although I set the parameters properly within the application context, the query always returns no result. I have tried the same query without the group by and the aggregated fields, then I can get the data (of course without any grouping).

If I want to get the "group by" data property, I have to add the dummy statement "rownum >= 0" hack as the last statement in the where clause, i.e.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW VW_SALT_RAW_SUMMARY AS
(
    select
        VENDOR_ID, PRD_CATEGORY, LOGIN_NAME, CURRENCY /*, Some more aggregated fields*/
    from
        VENDOR_RECORD
    where
        (
            order_time between SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptBeginTime') and SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptEndTime')
            AND order_time between SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_BEGIN_TIME') AND SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_END_TIME')
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID') = '*'
                or
                (
                    VENDOR_ID in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptVENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID') = '*'
                or
                (
                    VENDOR_ID in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_VENDOR_ID'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    PRD_CATEGORY in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptPRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    PRD_CATEGORY in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        and
        (
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME') = '*'
                or
                (
                    LOGIN_NAME in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'rptLOGIN_NAME'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
            AND
            (
                SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY') = '*'
                or
                (
                    LOGIN_NAME in
                    (
                        select
                            regexp_substr(SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+',1, rownum) str
                        from
                            dual connect by level <= regexp_count (SYS_CONTEXT('CTX_ALERT', 'RESTRICT_PRD_CATEGORY'), '[^, ]+')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        -- A DIRTY HACK TO MAKE THE QUERY RETURNS DATA
        AND ROWNUM >= 0
    group by
        VENDOR_ID, PRD_CATEGORY, LOGIN_NAME, CURRENCY
)
```

;

This problem makes me crazy and I would like to ask for the reason behind, thanks.

EDITED: 
Some more information about VENDOR_RECORD

- Oracle Version:  11g (11.2.0.4.0)
- It is a extremely huge archive table (> 10M records per date), and partitioned by "order_time"
- It is purposed to be an analytical DB but not a real time transaction DB, hence very real time response are not necessary. On the other hand, the accuracy is important.

Comment: I'd guess this is an Oracle bug related to hash aggregation.  It might help to tell us your exact version number.  There are two different ways to group data in Oracle.  The newer hash group by is often faster but is more likely to cause problems.  Simplify your code as much as possible, compare the explain plans, and see if the  difference is an operation like "HASH GROUP BY" versus "SORT GROUP BY".  If a patch or upgrade can't fix the problem perhaps you can run `alter session set "_gby_hash_aggregation_enabled" = true;` or use a hint like `/*+ no_use_hash_aggregation*/`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks weird, but you can debug your code by making some conditions in your view  as comment, I believe you will figure out what line causing the problem. Adding "AND rownum > 0" is not enough to debug it, if the query looks complex make it simply first.

Comment: I have tried to remove the "group by" and the aggregated fields then this query can retrieve the data I need from the table. The reason it looks weird is that the users are allowed to input '*' to query all and also use "," to sepecify multiple inputs. I try to add more information about the table in the original post.